# How to read a Json object from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: json, ajax, servlets, httprequest, struts

I'm sending a json object from a ajax call to java.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'AddPPCheques.ws',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "chequesList=" + JSON.stringify(myJson),
    success: function (data) {

    }
}
);
```

Browser Console ->

```
chequesList=[{"Bank Code":"4234-322","Cheque No":"23432232","Amount":"432432","Commission":"427","Today":"2018-06-08"},{"Bank Code":"4234-112","Cheque No":"778787","Amount":"8986787","Commission":"2323","Today":"2018-06-08"}]
```

In java side im trying to read it from a HttpServletRequest.

```
public ActionForward addCheques(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject ( request.getParameter("chequesList").toString() );

}
```

But I get a NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong here? And how to read the json object details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you pass the data as `JSON` but you want to get it as String and invoke `toString()`,but you will get null so NullPointerException will happen

So change your `ajax` code to below:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'AddPPCheques.ws',
    type: "POST",
    data: {chequesList:JSON.stringify(myJson)},
    success: function (data) {

    }
}
);
```